# How to remove hover status on touch screen?

Tags: jquery, hover, touchscreen, jquery-hover

I'm trying to remove hover status using jQuery 3.3.1:

```
$("#read-all").click(function(read_all) {

    read_all.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        // some code
    });

    // >> Here << I'm trying to remove hover status  
});
```

HTML

```
<a id="read-all" href="http://...">Mark All as read</a>
```

PreventDefault, AJAX is working well. But I can't remove hover status on mobile. I have tried many variations that was suggested in other answers, including:

```
$(this).unbind('hover');
$(this).off('mouseenter mouseleave');
$(this).unbind('mouseenter mouseleave');
```

But nothing is doing what I need and can't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: share yr html code

Answer (score 0):

if you mean you need to avoid the double touch, and go straight to elements, add this;

$("*").on("touchend", function(e) { $(this).focus(); });

You may need a jquery plugin to place in head script;

src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"